# Manage location-related notes

Tags: ios, notifications, reminders, geolocation

I have some information I'd like to keep track of, that is only relevant when I present in a particular physical location.  Ideally, I'd get a notification when I am near that location, and the notification would automatically delete itself when I leave; or failing that, there would be a way to manually look up any information I've previously saved that's relevant to my current location.

Is there a way to do this, on iOS?

Motivation: for instance, I find myself wanting to write down notes of what menu items I like to order when I'm at a particular restaurant, or bathroom codes at a specific building.

The closest I have found is that I can mark an item in the Reminders app to show up when arriving at a location.  However, the notification stays even after I have left that location and it is no longer relevant.  Is there a way to get the notification to automatically clear itself when I leave the location?

Comment: There could be a way to to this with Shortcuts I think. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Thinkr, no, I haven't.  Thank you for the idea!  I have no experience with Shortcuts.  I'd be interested to learn how to do this with Shortcuts.

Comment: I'll see if I can help

Comment: There is a way to make a shortcut that sends an alert or notification when you are in that place (or near it) but there is no actions that allows you to dismiss a notification.